# Decoding ByteArray to video and displaying in VideoView/Play movie in VideoView

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-videoview, movie

I've been trying to decode a bytearray into a video format (.mp4/etc) and to display in a VideoView. Anybody knows how to do this way? Another question that i'm asking if whether Movie format variables can be played on the VideoView.

Heres the code

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(checkType.substring(6), Base64.DEFAULT);

Movie mv = Movie.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,decodedString.length);
```

So how can I continue and play the movie/video on the VideoView?

Comment: Are you talking about streaming or non-streamed content? For non-streamed content: Just save it to SD and open it in a player. For streaming it gets a little bit more complicated.

Comment: We are trying to play a video that is not being saved anywhere. The video is being sent over from TCP Client, therefore we have to decode it and play on android.

Comment: How to do this depends heavily on the format you are using to encode the video. Do you use any library for packetization etc?

Comment: Apparently no becuz im just a beginner in java and have no clue how to solve this. the video format is in mp4.

Comment: I have tried to play video using URL. But what I really need is to send over the video from windows to play on android.

Comment: OK, this is very broad. I suggest you research "Streaming Video" and then rethink if this is good for you for a beginner's project. I guess not ;)

Comment: How do i convert a bytearray to a video file then?